How to check depth of nested parentheses using C# regular expressions?
fraction format : frac{numerator value}{denominator value}

input text : frac{frac{1}{2}}{frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}}
my pattern : frac\{(?:[^{}]|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))*\}\{(?:[^{}]|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))*\}(?(open)(?!))
i want output :
match → frac{frac{1}{2}}{frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}}
group1 → frac{frac{1}{2}}{frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}}
group2.1 → frac{1}{2}
group2.2 → frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}
group3 → frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}
group4 → frac{5}{6}
PS: The depths depicted in the picture are groups.
Is the above possible using regular expressions?

Can you have arbitrary nesting? Then the answer is no. Because the one thing regular expressions are really bad at, is handling nested structures and you might be better off building a specific parser for your structure

So, how can I get only the deepest bracket (depth4)?

Check this one. Click Table to see the results (there are i2 Group captures, too).

That's not the result I want. I want the deepest frac{}{} pattern

@knkyu Did you forget to click on the "2 captures" link in the page to expand the deeper captures?

The results you are expecting (group number equals to depth) is not possible, since an arbitrarily nested string would need an indefinite number of groups.
If the depth is limited
The solution is straightforward:
(?<%LEVEL%>frac{(?:\d+|%PATTERN%)}{(?:\d+|%PATTERN%)})

(?<1>frac{(?:\d+|(?<2>frac{(?:\d+|(?<3>frac{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}))}{(?:\d+|(?<3>frac{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}))}))}{(?:\d+|(?<2>frac{(?:\d+|(?<3>frac{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}))}{(?:\d+|(?<3>frac{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}{(?:\d+|(?<4>frac{\d+}{\d+}))}))}))})

Try it on regex101.com.
Such a pattern could be generated using this script, in case you need more than 4:


function generate(depth) {
  const format = String.raw`frac{(?:\d+|(?<%i>%s))}{(?:\d+|(?<%i>%s))}`;
  let result = `(?<1>${format})`;
  for (let level = 2; level < depth; level++) {
    result = result.replaceAll('%i', level).replaceAll('%s', format);
  }
  result = result
    .replaceAll('%i', depth)
    .replaceAll('%s', String.raw`frac{\d+}{\d+}`);
  return result;
}

const input = document.querySelector('#depth');
const output = document.querySelector('#result');
const button = document.querySelector('#generate');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  output.textContent = generate(~~input.value)
});

input.value = 4;
button.click();
#result {
  max-width: 100vw;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-wrap: wrap;
}
<input type="number" id="depth" min="2" step="1">
<button id="generate">Generate</button>

<pre id="result"></pre>



If the depth is known
You could count the braces up until the deepest frac{}{}:
^(?>frac|\d+|(?<s>{)|(?<-s>}))+
(frac{\d+}{\d+})

...then verify that the number of levels in the stack is exactly equals to some number:
(?=(?<-s>){3}(?(s)(?!)))

Try it on regex101.com.
I'm not sure whether comparing depth is possible, however.

This solution is a combination of regex and C# code. The result is a tree structure where you can grab what you are looking for.
The number of Groups is only depending on the regex pattern that is used. It has nothing to do with the input text. But the resulting elements in each group’s capture collection is depending on the input text.
Using the pattern described in Microsoft's article on balancing groups:
Balancing group definitions
^[^\{\}]*(((?'Open'\{)[^\{\}]*)+((?'Close-Open'\})[^\{\}]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))$

The "Close" group will keep the result as a flat collection in it's capture collection. There is no obvious information in the captured elements that tells you about the level or parent / child or something like that. But since the position in the text is given, it is possible to find out the parent/child relationship. I have written a function to transform this flat collection to a tree structure.
The "AddCapture" function is creating the tree from the capture collection based on the position in the input text. The collection is read from bottom up since the last one seems to be the highest level.
The "WriteTree" function displays a graphical view of the tree in the output window:
frac{frac{1}{2}}{frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}}
          |-------------> frac{1}{2}
          |                        |--------> 1
          |                        |--------> 2
          |-------------> frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}
                                   |--------> 3
                                   |--------> frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}
                                                   |----> 4
                                                   |----> frac{5}{6}
                                                               |----> 5
                                                               |----> 6

The code is made in a C# Console App (net 8) project:
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/*
 * ========================================================================================
 * This code is created for this answer. It is not thouroughly tested!
 * Only tested with the input string from the question.
 * ========================================================================================
 */

string text = @"frac{frac{1}{2}}{frac{3}{frac{4}{frac{5}{6}}}}";

Node treeTop = null;    //The resulting tree top node

Dictionary<int, int> capLength = new Dictionary<int, int>();      //Is the max length of the captured texts. Used only for displaying the tree.

//The pattern is based on Microsofts article on balancing groups
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"^[^\{\}]*(((?'Open'\{)[^\{\}]*)+((?'Close-Open'\})[^\{\}]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))$"))
{
    //========== Create the tree from the "Close" group. =============
    Group? g = m.Groups.GetValueOrDefault("Close");
    if (g != null)
    {
        //This is the entire string for the match (top level)
        treeTop = new Node() { Value = m.Value, Pos = m.Index, Length = m.Index + m.Length };
        //Go backward to start with the highest level
        for (int i = g.Captures.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            //Each capture is a node in the tree
            Capture cap = g.Captures[i];
            //Add the captured node to the tree
            AddCapture(treeTop, cap);
            
            //This part is only for the display of the tree (used in WriteTree function)
            int lev = g.Captures.Count - 1 - i;
            if (capLength.ContainsKey(lev))
                capLength[lev] = Math.Max(cap.Length, capLength[lev]);
            else
                capLength.Add(lev, cap.Length);
        };
    };
}

//==========  Display the tree in the output window ========== 
Debug.WriteLine(new string('=', treeTop.Value.Length));
Debug.WriteLine(treeTop?.Value);
WriteTree(treeTop, 1, false, capLength);
Debug.WriteLine("");


static bool AddCapture(Node node, Capture capture)
{
    bool isAdded = false;
    //Go from the top level and found the deepest child that contains the position for the capture
    foreach (Node child in node.Children)
    {
        if (capture.Index >= child.Pos && capture.Index <= child.Pos + child.Length)
        {
            if (child.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                //Go one level deeper to see if the capture fits on a lower level
                isAdded = AddCapture(child, capture);
            }
            if (!isAdded)
            {
                //If not found on a deeper level, add the capture to the sibling collection
                Node entry = new Node() { Value = capture.Value, Pos = capture.Index, Length = capture.Length };
                child.Children.Add(entry);
                isAdded = true;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    if (!isAdded)
    {
        //If the node doesn't have any children, add the capture as child to the node
        Node entry = new Node() { Value = capture.Value, Pos = capture.Index, Length = capture.Length };
        node.Children.Add(entry);
        isAdded = true;
    }
    return isAdded;
};

static void WriteTree(Node node, int level, bool lastChild, Dictionary<int, int> capLength)
{
    //Displays the tree in the output window

    List<Node> ReversedList = node.Children;
    ReversedList.Reverse();
    foreach (Node child in ReversedList)
    {
        string childLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        {
            int cLength = Math.Max(capLength[i], 10);
            if (i < level - 1)
            {
                if (!lastChild)
                    childLine += (new string(' ', cLength / 2) + "| " + new string(' ', cLength / 2));
                else
                childLine += (new string(' ', cLength / 2) + "  " + new string(' ', cLength / 2));
            }
            else
                childLine += (new string(' ', cLength / 2) + "|" + new string('-', (cLength / 2) - 1) + "> ");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(childLine + child.Value);
        if (child.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            WriteTree(child, level + 1, child == node.Children.Last(), capLength);
        }
    }
};

class Node
{
    public string Value;
    public int Pos;
    public int Length;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}


i not use Group? g = m.Groups.GetValueOrDefault("Close");
